# How to open csv file which contains special characters in one of the fields in csv?

Tags: csv, exception, xamarin.forms

hi I am working on a xamarin.forms app, While trying to open one of the csv file the following exception is displayed "input string is not in a correct format " the  csv file contains a field called item name which consists the following names **ET Door,E459-2,H 91 Ft** and **Key,Door**  so these both items contain comma so I am not able to open the csv file which consists of these two elements as they contain special characters like comma and underscore .Here is my code to read and open csv file ,please check the code and let me know what changes do i need to make so the file with items consisting of special characters also open ?

```
  public async void OnProcess(object o, EventArgs args)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csv_file.Text))
        {
          //  _database.AddFiles();

            if (App.Current.MainPage is NavigationPage)
            {
                try
                {

                    List<ItemsCSV> items = new List<ItemsCSV>();
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(string.Format(@"{0}", this.file.FilePath));
                    if (lines != null)
                    {
                        for (int x = 1; x < lines.Length; x++)
                        {

                            string data = lines[x];


                            string[] item = data.Split(',');

                            //  ItemsCSV itemsCSV = new ItemsCSV();
                            _itemsCSV = new ItemsCSV();
                            {
                                _itemsCSV.Cycle_Count = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ElementAtOrDefault(0)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item[0]);
                                _itemsCSV.Line_Number = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ElementAtOrDefault(1)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item[1]);
                                _itemsCSV.Item_Number = item.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
                                _itemsCSV.Name = item.ElementAtOrDefault(3);
                                _itemsCSV.Warehouse = item.ElementAtOrDefault(4);
                                _itemsCSV.Aisle = item.ElementAtOrDefault(5);
                                _itemsCSV.Bin = item.ElementAtOrDefault(6);
                                _itemsCSV.Level = item.ElementAtOrDefault(7);
                                _itemsCSV.Order_Qty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ElementAtOrDefault(8)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item[8]);
                                _itemsCSV.Order_UOM = item.ElementAtOrDefault(9);
                                _itemsCSV.Consumption_Qty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ElementAtOrDefault(10)) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(item[10]);
                                _itemsCSV.Consumption_UOM = item.ElementAtOrDefault(11);
                                _itemsCSV.Status = "";

                            };
                            items.Add(_itemsCSV);
                            _database.AddItems(_itemsCSV);

                        }

                        var result = await DisplayAlert("", "CSV has been processed, please do cycle count", "OK", "Cancel");

                        if(result == true)
                        {
                            var cyclecountPage = new CycleCountPage(items, 0, "MainPage",this.file.FilePath);
                            await (App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync(cyclecountPage);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "File is empty", "OK");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Exception", e.Message, "OK");
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "File name is mandatory", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: can you please explain how is this related to solve the issue ?  I have checked the link but I did not find anything to resolve my issue.Thanks

Comment: it's a library for parsing CSV files.  I personally would rather use that than try to manually parse one like you are doing.  It should also easily handle the embedded comma